# How can I disable a reserved profile?

Tags: profile

I have a profile that was created by some user and and went into "Reserved Profile" List. The bots are attacking the profile and creating contacts, since the form is public facing and no captcha was added. The form also does not give a option to disable or delete or settings. Can anyone suggest how do I remove this form completely? If can be done using mysql which table and values should be altered?

[image]Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use api explorer(civicrm/api) to disable the reserved profile

[image]

or if you have access to database then run sql to update the profile

UPDATE civicrm_uf_group SET is_active = 0 WHERE id = 10;

Comment: thanks Pradeep.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually still edit it and uncheck the active box you just have to hack the url to use the id, e.g.

https://site-url/civicrm/admin/uf/group/update?action=update&id=22&context=group

Then the active checkbox is near the bottom.